# How to mine private node blocks on remote machine

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, private-blockchain

In testing purposes I started private ethereum node on server and made it's api address public via nginx.

`geth --networkid 4224 --datadir "" --nodiscover --rpc --rpcport "8545" --port "30303" --rpccorsdomain "*" --nat "any" --rpcapi eth,web3,personal,net,miner --ipcpath ""`

I'm sure it must be possible to somehow mine it's blocks remotely from my pc. Is it?

Answer (score 1):

Mining is done on the node itself. If you want to mine on your PC you should install `geth` on your PC and mine this private chain. Just `admin.addPeer()` to connect to the node you started and then `miner.start(1)`

You don't need to export RPC api to the world, it isn't required for mining.

Comment: Is it the only way? (to mine on node itself) The problem is that I want node to live on server with 1gb of RAM.